# How to use a new serial ID for each new batch of inserted rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequence

Is it possible to use a sequence for a batch of rows, versus getting a new ID on each insert? I'm keeping track of a set of details, and I want the sequence to apply for the set, not each individual row. So my data should look like so:

```
id batch_id name  dept
1    99     John  Engineering
2    99     Amy   Humanities
3    99     Bill  Science
4    99     Jack  English
```

It's the `batch_id` that I want Postgres to issue as a sequence. Is this possible?

Comment: Define `batch_id ` as `batch_id bigint not null default currval('seqname')` and call `nextval('seqname')` manually before inserting batch of rows.

Comment: @Abelisto: The solution would make a fine answer.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter My comment was too simple for the answer and you forced me to make something more complex :)

Comment: @Abelisto: And I don't feel bad about it. ;) Even a finer answer, yet.

Comment: @Abelisto Thank you! Can you put your comment in an answer, please?

Comment: I already answered here before. Added the comment to the existing answer.

Answer (score 5):

Define batch_id as `batch_id bigint not null default currval('seqname')` and call `nextval('seqname')` manually before inserting batch of rows.

Or, for the full automation:

1) Create sequence for the batch id:

```
create sequence mytable_batch_id;
```

2) Create your table, declare batch id field as below:

```
create table mytable (
    id bigserial not null primary key,
    batch_id bigint not null default currval('mytable_batch_id'),
    name text not null);
```

3) Create statement level trigger to increment the batch id sequence:

```
create function tgf_mytable_batch_id() returns trigger language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    perform nextval('mytable_batch_id');
    return null;
end $$;

create trigger tg_mytablebatch_id
before insert on mytable
for each statement execute procedure tgf_mytable_batch_id();
```

Now each single statement when you inserting data into the table will be interpreted as next single batch.

Example:

```
postgres=# insert into mytable (name) values('John'), ('Amy'), ('Bill');
INSERT 0 3
postgres=# insert into mytable (name) values('Jack');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# insert into mytable (name) values('Jimmmy'), ('Abigail');
INSERT 0 2
postgres=# table mytable;
 id | batch_id |    name     
----+----------+-------------
  1 |        1 | John
  2 |        1 | Amy
  3 |        1 | Bill
  4 |        2 | Jack
  5 |        3 | Jimmy
  6 |        3 | Abigail
(6 rows)
```